Pytest + async playwright: tests execution hangs forever after first test passes
I'm using async_playwright in Python. When I want to add unit tests, I need to create a shared browser and page for each test case. I'm using pytest_asyncio to create fixtures for that.
This is my conftest.py file:
import pytest_asyncio
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

from src.page_object.factory.playwright import PWPageOjectFactory


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope="session")
def event_loop(request):
    """Create an instance of the default event loop for each test case."""
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope="module")
async def browser():
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch()
        yield browser
        await browser.close()


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope="module")
async def page(browser):
    factory = PWPageOjectFactory("https://www.google.com", browser)
    print(factory.url)
    page = await factory.create_page_object()
    print(page)
    return page

And this is my test file:
import pytest

from src.page_object.element.playwright import PWElement
from src.page_object.page.playwright import PWPageObject

pytest_plugins = ("pytest_asyncio",)


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_po_factory(page):
    assert page is not None
    assert isinstance(page, PWPageObject)


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_active_element(page):
    element = await page.get_active_element()
    assert element is not None
    assert isinstance(element, PWElement)


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_navigate(page):
    element = await page.get_active_element()
    await page.navigate_forward()
    new_element = await page.get_active_element()
    assert element.get_attribute("id") != new_element.get_attribute("id")
    await page.navigate_backward()
    new_element = await page.get_active_element()
    assert element.get_attribute("id") == new_element.get_attribute("id")

When I execute pytest tests (where tests is the folder that contains the previous files), the first test case passes and then the execution gets stuck forever.
What am I missing here?
Things I have tried:

I had the module scoped fixtures in the test file before and the behavior was the same. I understand that it doesn't change anything.
I removed the event_loop fixture from the conftest.py file and got the same result.
I have been looking for ways to run all my tests without using the Playwright plugin for pytest since I think there should be a way to run my tests without it.
I found a similar question here, but it has no answer so I'm asking about my specific case that also involves playwright.

Update (2024-04-25)
This is the output of pytest -vvv -s:
(example) C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\projects\example>pytest -vvv -s
================================================= test session starts =================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.12.2, pytest-8.1.1, pluggy-1.4.0 -- C:\Users\MyUser\miniconda3\envs\example\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\projects\example
plugins: asyncio-0.23.6
asyncio: mode=Mode.STRICT
collected 5 items

tests/test_pageobject.py::test_po_factory https://www.google.com
<src.page_object.page.playwright.PWPageObject object at 0x0000018A4EA38FB0>
PASSED
tests/test_pageobject.py::test_get_active_element

The process stays stuck forever :(
Maybe other details I didn't mention:

I'm developing inside a conda environment
I'm using a Windows machine


Can you post output of pytest -vvv -s?

@Shod I added the requested info. Thanks a lot for reviewing my issue!

i can suggest you 2 things - try to replace return with yield in the page fixture, and secondly try to add a pdb in test_get_active_element, run pytest and check line-by-line.. i suspect some issue in the get_active_element method

The solution is - add a loop_scope param to the asyncio marker in the test and set it to module.
Like this:
@pytest.mark.asyncio(loop_scope="module")
async def test_po_factory(page):
    assert page is not None
    assert isinstance(page, PWPageObject)

Add this parameter to all the tests in the module.
And you can remove the event_loop fixture.
Reference - asyncio event loops
